# Store result of a curl request / api call into a javascript file

Tags: javascript, curl

I am able to successfully make an api call using a curl request using the command line.

curl -D - "https://api.hostsite.../"

However, I would like to take the returned data and be able to manipulate it in a .js file.

It works if I copy and paste the data into the file but would like to access the data just by running the .js file so that I can make multiple requests more easily.

I tried to using an ajax call but was wondering if there was an easier way I could do this without configuring the server and enabling CORS, which I was having some difficulty doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the API you are using doesn't support CORS (You can't do it yourself, the API has to support it because CORS is added in the headers of the response), you can use an intermediate language to make the curl request. (E.g. PHP)

From a Javascript file you can make a AJAX request to the PHP file containing the curl request. You just need to 'echo' the response from your PHP file and voilà, you get the response in your Javascript.

If you need more detailed information or help with the implementation please say something.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result by using a bash script to populate the curl request data into a JSON file.

```
#script.sh
curl "https://data-api" > file-name.JSON
curl "https://data-api" >> file-name.json

node project/calculate.js
```

And then have the bash script run the .js file which reads the data from the JSON files.

```
$ ./script.sh
```